# Azure IPSecurity to update Cloud Service Firewall

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, azure, azure-cloud-services

I would like to use the IPSecurity to update my cloud service's firewalls in order to lock down our dev environemnts and block specific ip's on our produciton environments.

It looks like it's possible now from the post below...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/12/09/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx?Redirected=true

Does anyone know if it's possible to have a dynamic list that is stored in a Service Configuration file and then have IPSecurity use that list?  Then I'd like to be able to change that config without having to redeploy the cloud service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get it to work using IPSecurity and Web.config either.

What DID work for cloud services was using ACLs in ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg

See this post for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walterm/archive/2014/04/22/windows-azure-paas-acls-are-here.aspx

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I believe this Azure's supported way of doing this going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the link you provided is for Azure Web Sites, not Cloud Services, though settings in IIS on Cloud Services would also work, having the same redeployment issue you are talking about.

Something that close to what you are talking about can be found on Sandrino's blog, (posted in Jan, 2013) "[Apply IP address restrictions to your Windows Azure Cloud Services](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/apply-ip-address-restrictions-to-your-windows-azure-cloud-services/)".

You can ACL VM endpoints remotely, but I don't think that has been extended to cloud services yet, but my Google-Fu may have just failed me.